# L-BFGS Optimizer Not Changing Loss But Adam Is

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, neural-network, pytorch

I am building a physics-informed neural network to approximate PDEs. I am getting okay results with just using the adam optimizer however I want to get better results. I am attempting to use adam for say 10,000 iteration then the L-BFGS optimizer (pytorch) for the last 1,000.

However when using my L-BFGS optimizer the loss of the network never changes and remain constant. Here is my closure function used in my PINN for L-BFGS

```
def closure(self):
    lbfgs_optim.zero_grad()  
    train_loss = PINN.loss(xt_train_ICBC, u_train_ICBC, xt_resid, f_hat_train)
    train_loss.backward()      
    return train_loss
```

Also my optimizer paramters for both adam and L-BFGS

```
epochs_adam, epochs_lbfgs  = 10000, 1000
adam_optim  = torch.optim.Adam(PINN.parameters(), lr=lr, weight_decay=1e-5)
lbfgs_optim = torch.optim.LBFGS(PINN.parameters(), lr=lr, history_size = 20,
                                max_iter = 50, line_search_fn = "strong_wolfe")
```

I am using one for loop for adam then another for loop for L-BFGS, here is how adam is used in my code, which works

```
train_loss = PINN.loss(xt_train_ICBC, u_train_ICBC, xt_resid, f_hat_train)
... # print loss's, append to lists
adam_optim.zero_grad()
train_loss.backward()
adam_optim.step()
```

Then for my L-BFGS, which seems not to work, all I call in my epoch loop is

```
lbfgs_optim.step(PINN.closure)
```

and I don't see any changes in the loss, why is that?

Versions being used: Python 3.9.12, PyTorch 1.11.0 and NumPy 1.21.5

EDIT: PINN code, and optimization/training code

```
class NN(nn.Module):
    # Heat Equation PDE    
    def __init__(self, layers):
        super().__init__()
        self.activation = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.loss_function = nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')
        self.linears = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(layers[i], layers[i+1]) for i in range(len(layers)-1)])

        for i in range(len(layers)-1):
            nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.linears[i].weight.data, gain=1.0)
            nn.init.zeros_(self.linears[i].bias.data)  
    
    def forward(self, x):        
        a = x.float()
        for i in range(0, len(layers)-2):
            z = self.linears[i](a)
            a = self.activation(z)
        a = self.linears[-1](a)
        return a
    
    def lossICBC(self, x_ICBC, u_ICBC):
        """MSE losses for oundary and initial conditions"""
        loss_ICBC = self.loss_function(self.forward(x_ICBC), u_ICBC)
        return loss_ICBC
    
    def lossPDE(self, xt_residual, f_hat):
        """Residual loss for collocation points"""
        g = xt_residual.clone().float()
        g.requires_grad=True

        f = self.forward(g)
        
        f_xt = autograd.grad(f, g, torch.ones(g.shape[0], 1).to(device), create_graph=True)[0]
        f_xx_tt = autograd.grad(f_xt, g, torch.ones(g.shape).to(device), create_graph=True)[0]
        
        f_t = f_xt[:,[1]] # extract just the t values
        f_xx = f_xx_tt[:,[0]] # extract just the x values
        
        f = f_t - k*f_xx 
        return self.loss_function(f, f_hat)

    def closure(self):
        lbfgs_optim.zero_grad()  
        train_loss = PINN.loss(xt_train_ICBC, u_train_ICBC, xt_resid, f_hat_train)
        train_loss.backward()      
        return train_loss
    
    def loss(self, x_ICBC, u_ICBC, xt_residual, f_hat):
        """Total loss"""
        loss_ICBC = self.lossICBC(x_ICBC, u_ICBC)
        loss_PDE  = self.lossPDE(xt_residual, f_hat) #f_hat=torch.zeros()
        return loss_PDE + loss_ICBC
```

```
lr_adam = 0.001
lr_lbfgs = 1
epochs_adam  = 20000
adam_optim   = torch.optim.Adam(PINN.parameters(), lr=lr)

epochs_lbfgs = 100
lbfgs_optim  = torch.optim.LBFGS(PINN.parameters(), lr=15, history_size = 20,
                                 max_iter = 50, line_search_fn = "strong_wolfe")
```

Training loops

```
for i in range(0, epochs_adam+1):

    train_loss = PINN.loss(xt_train_ICBC, u_train_ICBC, xt_resid, f_hat_train)
    adam_optim.zero_grad()
    train_loss.backward()
    adam_optim.step()
```

```
for i in range(0, epochs_lbfgs+1):
    train_loss = lbfgs_optim.step(PINN.closure)
```

Comment: lbfgs typically has a larger lr than Adam, have you tried a larger lr? Also, does your `PINN.loss` function also regenerate its predictions?

Comment: @jhso Yes my `PINN.loss` computes the forward pass of the data then returns the loss. Before in lbfgs I was using an lr of 0.001, I've tried new lr's of 5 and 15 and no change.

Comment: Could you please provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), eg. the code of `PINN.loss` and ALL of your optimisation code. It is unclear how you track the PINN loss during LBFGS, and how you apply the two optimisation strategies in your code.

Comment: @jhso I've added the code for the network and the training loop as an edit to my question. There is more code in order to create the data points being used, it is fair amount and so as of right now I didn't want to include a very large amount of code. If you want me to add it then I can.